# How to check in which column is certain value in pandas.DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, filter

I have DataFrame in Python like below:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"col1"  : ["a", "b", "c"], "col2" : ["a", "d", "e"], "col3" : ["r", "t" , "g"]})
```

And I would like to check in which columns is value "a" (of course in "col1" and "col2"). How can I check it ?

Comment: How looks expected output ? It is `list`? Or `Series` ? Or filtered columns?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If need columns names in list compare all values by [`DataFrame.eq`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.eq.html) with [`DataFrame.any`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.any.html) for check if at least one `True` (match) per columns, last filter columns names:

```
c = df.columns[df.eq('a').any()].tolist()
print (c)
['col1', 'col2']
```

If need filter columns to new `DataFrame` use [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html):

```
df1 = df.loc[:, df.eq('a').any()]
print (df1)
  col1 col2
0    a    a
1    b    d
2    c    e
```

Answer (score 3):

```
(df=='a').any()

col1     True
col2     True
col3    False
```